# Meteor: how to get a collection item's _id?

Tags: meteor

Meteor only allows changing / removing collection items by the _id.  However, I cannot seem to find out how to get the _id of an item.

I am currently trying to store the _id in a variable after the item is inserted.

Comment: Collection.insert returns the newly inserted item _id.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to find the document by some random attribute, you must do `var myDoc = Collection.findOne({attr: attrValue})` and then call remove passing the _id `Collection.remove({_id: myDoc._id})`.

If you don't have an attribute to find an item, well, just store it in a var.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
collection.insert({name:"test"});
console.log (collection.find().fetch());
```

then you may able to see the _id in you console